# Issue with React hook state while working with lodash debounce

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

I'm not really sure what exactly is causing the issue. So I have a component that shows the amount of pictures according to certain actions. I have a slider and a dropdown component to simulate the actions.

I am using lodash debounce on the slider. So the exact issue is that I have a state to keep track of the filter with initial value say the category with dog

```js
const initialValue = {
  filters: [
    {
      field: "category",
      values: ["dog"]
    }
  ]
}
const [myFilter, setMyFilter] = useState(initialValue)
```

With the initial value above, the component will fetch all the pictures with category dog and display on the page. Then I am able to add a dropdown value to filter out say the image size, so then my state output as below:

```js
 myFilter = {
   filters: [
     {
       field: "category",
       values: ["dog"]
     },
     {
       field: "size",
       values: ["500x500"]
     }
   ]
 }
```

At this point my newest state should as above. I added a `debounce` for the time range so that the function looks like below

```js
onTimeRangeChange = (value) => {
  // update range state
  setRange(value);
}

const handleSetTimeRange = (value: number[]) => {
    const merge = {
      time_range: {
        start_time: moment(startTime + value[0] * 1000).toISOString(),
        end_time: moment(startTime + value[1] * 1000).toISOString(),
      },
    };

    console.log("myFilter: ", myFilter);
    setMyFilter({ ...myFilter, time_range: merge });
  };

const handleDebounce = useCallback(debounce(handleSetTimeRange, 500), [])

useEffect(() => {
  if(prevRange && oneRange !== prevRange)
  {
     handleDebounce(range)
  }
}, [range])
```

so `myFilter` after all is expected to be

```js
  myFilter = {
    filters: [
     {
       field: "category",
       values: ["dog"]
     },
     {
       field: "size",
       values: ["500x500"]
     }
   ],
   time_range: {
        start_time: moment(startTime + value[0] * 1000).toISOString(),
        end_time: moment(startTime + value[1] * 1000).toISOString(),
   }
 }
```

but instead the actual value is shown as below:

```js
myFilter = {
    filters: [
     {
       field: "category",
       values: ["dog"]
     }
   ],
   time_range: {
        start_time: moment(startTime + value[0] * 1000).toISOString(),
        end_time: moment(startTime + value[1] * 1000).toISOString(),
   }
 }
```

Somehow it removed the size object under the filters. Im not sure what is actually happening, Im not very familiar with debounce and useCallback. Do they reset the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `useCallback` hook has an empty dependency array,

```
const handleDebounce = useCallback(debounce(handleSetTimeRange, 500), []);
```

so the initial `myFilter` state value is closed over in callback scope and never updated.

```
const handleSetTimeRange = (value: number[]) => {
  const merge = {
    time_range: {
      start_time: moment(startTime + value[0] * 1000).toISOString(),
      end_time: moment(startTime + value[1] * 1000).toISOString(),
    },
  };

  console.log("myFilter: ", myFilter);
  setMyFilter({ ...myFilter, time_range: merge });
};
```

You can likely either add `myFilter` to the `useCallback` hook's dependency array to reenclose the updated `myFilter` state value in callback scope:

```
const handleDebounce = useCallback(
  debounce(handleSetTimeRange, 500),
  [myFilter],
);
```

or use a functional state update to correctly update from any previous state:

```
const handleSetTimeRange = (value: number[]) => {
  const merge = {
    time_range: {
      start_time: moment(startTime + value[0] * 1000).toISOString(),
      end_time: moment(startTime + value[1] * 1000).toISOString(),
    },
  };

  setMyFilter(myFilter => {
    return {
      ...myFilter,
      time_range: merge
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks man, didn't know we could pass in a function to the setState in React hooks. It works now!

Comment: @user14459580 Yup, you sure can! Glad to help. Cheers and good luck!